# Creating a dataframe using 3 other data frames that have no common merge values

Tags: r, loops, optimization, conditional-statements

I'm trying to accomplish a very particular type of data cleaning process using R.

I am given 2 dataframe structures and one matrix structure. The matrix corresponds to `DF1` as column headers and `DF2` as row headers, but I want to take all of this data and convert to a rectangular dataframe with one observation per row (based on result matrix, `matrix_data`).

Using the code below, I am able to create one observation per row, but for large data sets (~1M+ unique entries), this can take **several** minutes to run (~5 min). Right now, I am using a for loop to cycle through `DF1`, and I'm using `do.call(... replicate())` to append rows to `DF2`. Treatment of the `matrix_data` is simple - I unwrap the data into a vector and cbind it to the `DF1_ext` and `DF2_ext` dataframes. Is there a better way to execute this `for()` loop in R?

```
DF1 <- data.frame(x_1 = c('a','b','c','d','e'), y_1 = c('f','g','h','i','j'), z_1 = c('k','l','m','n','o'))
DF2 <- data.frame(v_2 = 1:3, w_2 = 4:6, x_2 = 7:9, y_2 = 10:12, z_2 = 13:15)
matrix_data <- matrix(data = 1:15, nrow = 3, ncol = 5)


DF1_ext <- NULL
DF1_length <- nrow(DF1) * nrow(DF2)

#Use ceiling function to determine which row to put in NULL dataframe
#i.e. ceiling() rounds up to nearest integer value, setting j = to incremental step in origin dataframe
#See resultant DF

for (k in 1:DF1_length) {
  j = ceiling(k / DF1_length * length(DF1[,2]))
  DF1_ext <- rbind(DF1_ext[], DF1[j,])
}

#replicate DF2 matrix with rbind() based on the number of rows in DF1
DF2_ext <- do.call(rbind, replicate(nrow(DF1), DF2, simplify = FALSE))

#cbind() all values together. 
#matrix_data can be transposed or not. This matters in the actual analysis, but should not matter here. 
DF_result <- cbind(DF1_ext, DF2_ext, as.vector(t(matrix_data)))

View(DF_result)
```

I am seeking a more "R" way of executing this code, hoping that there may be some more efficient functions along the way. This code, as is, can be copied into R and run with only base functions. To be clear, I am seeking a better way of executing in R because this method executes very slowly, and it seems like a lot of running around to do compared to most R methodology.

Comment: Every row in `DF1` is replicated three times, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done pretty simply with the `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
test <- DF1 %>% mutate(list_col = list(DF2)) %>% unnest() %>% 
  mutate(matrix_data = as.vector(t(matrix_data)))
```

Basically it repeats `DF2` as much as needed to fill all the rows in `DF1` and then `unnest` repeats each row of `DF1` for each row in `DF2`.

Answer (score 2):

What about the data.table package? `rbindlist` is a must faster alternative to `rbind`.

Also, @akrun suggested `bind_rows` from `dplyr`, which is also much faster than `do.call`.

```
library(data.table)
DF2_ext <- rbindlist(replicate(nrow(DF1), DF2, simplify = FALSE))

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(do.call(rbind, replicate(nrow(DF1), DF2, simplify = FALSE)),
           rbindlist(replicate(nrow(DF1), DF2, simplify = FALSE)),
           bind_rows(replicate(nrow(DF1), DF2, simplify = FALSE)),
           cbind(sqldf("select * from DF1 join DF2"), data = c(t(matrix_data))))

Unit: microseconds
expr       min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval cld
do.call(rbind, replicate(nrow(DF1), DF2, simplify = FALSE))   424.572   451.0790   515.0016   473.8225   500.0185  1243.674   100  a 
rbindlist(replicate(nrow(DF1), DF2, simplify = FALSE))   105.988   124.3765   164.1111   159.7705   173.8210   563.697   100  a 
bind_rows(replicate(nrow(DF1), DF2, simplify = FALSE))    36.590    48.9140   528.4883    62.6580    75.0540 46448.825   100  a 
cbind(sqldf("select * from DF1 join DF2"), data = c(t(matrix_data))) 15201.367 15771.5310 18581.6682 16308.9790 18329.5940 54964.681   100   b
```

Comment: Most of my issue wasn't with the actual cbind process, but I was eating 90% of my processing time on the small ``for()`` loop in the code. I will also implement this and test with my data set. Perhaps a hybrid approach (SQL + rbindlist) will optimize the code completely

Answer (score 1):

Perform the join using SQL and then `cbind` the unravelled transpose of `matrix_data`.

```
library(sqldf)
cbind(sqldf("select * from DF1 join DF2"), data = c(t(matrix_data)))
```